# SFTP server containing error with message as ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: sftp

when we are trying to SSH on sftp server as -
**ssh fd@sftp-staging-server.com**

it's giving an error like- 
**ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer**

what can be the possible solution for this?

Comment: Means what it says: The remote side is cutting the connection. *Why* it cuts the connection is something you need to look at the server for.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su]. Also, there are a lot of questions about that error message, so you should check those out before opening a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have been blocked by server, so server may drop the connection in this case. For finding the root cause here, server-side logs will help.
**Connection reset by peer** means the TCP stream was abnormally closed from the other end.